# Oracle Java 7 as default and one in the system?

Tags: java, oracle

I got successfully installed Oracle Java on 12.04 and set it as default, I wanted to know is it safe and ok to remove Icedtea and OpenJDK6 and all that belongs to it and stick only Oracle Java and if I ever want to re-install Icedtea back later it will be ok?
this is my output:

```
0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java         1062      auto mode
1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
2 *          /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java         1062      manual mode
```

also what difference does it make manual or auto mode?

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's okay to do so, unless you're running some software that specifically requires openjdk. Most probably you are not. Also, yes, you can install IcedTea back later on if needed.

`man 8 update-alternatives` tells

```
   automatic mode
          When a link group is in automatic mode, the alternatives system
          ensures that the links in the group point to the highest priority
          alternative appropriate for the group.

   manual mode
          When a link group is in manual mode, the alternatives system will 
          not make any changes to the system administrator's settings.
```

Basically, in automatic mode, installing new package might change the default. In manual mode, what you choose will stay.

Comment: yes I remember I will in 10 mins :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't remember that. It's good feature, though. You might get better answers. :-)